When Jesus read from the Scroll of Isaiah, did he translate it into Aramaic?
What language did Jesus speak when he read Isaiah 61:1,2? Would Aramaic be spoken in the synagogue?

Luke 4:16-19 New International Version 16 He went to Nazareth, where
he had been brought up, and on the Sabbath day he went into the
synagogue, as was his custom. He stood up to read, 17 and the scroll
of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him. Unrolling it, he found the
place where it is written: 18 “The Spirit of the Lord is on me,
because he has anointed me
to proclaim good newsto the poor. He has sent me to proclaim freedom for the prisoners
and recovery of sight for the blind, to set the oppressed free, 19     to proclaim the year of the Lord’s favor.”

Research:
Language of Jesus - Wikipedia

There exists a consensus among scholars that the language of Jesus and
his disciples was Aramaic.[1][2] Aramaic was the common language of
Judea in the first century AD. The villages of Nazareth and Capernaum
in Galilee, where Jesus spent most of his time, were Aramaic-speaking
communities.[3] Jesus probably spoke a Galilean variant of the
language, distinguishable from that of Jerusalem.[4] Based on the
symbolic renaming or nicknaming of some of his apostles it is also
likely that Jesus and at least one of his apostles knew enough Koine
Greek to converse with those not native to Judea. It is reasonable to
assume that Jesus was well versed in Hebrew for religious
purposes.[5][6][7][8]

What Language Did Jesus Speak? | HISTORY
In particular, there’s been some confusion in the past about what language Jesus spoke, as a man living during the first century A.D. in the kingdom of Judea, located in what is now the southern part of Palestine.
The issue of Jesus’ preferred language memorably came up in 2014, during a public meeting in Jerusalem between Benjamin Netanyahu, the prime minister of Israel, and Pope Francis, during the pontiff’s tour of the Holy Land. Speaking to the pope through an interpreter, Netanyahu declared:

“Jesus was here, in this land. He spoke Hebrew.”
Francis broke in, correcting him. “Aramaic,” he said, referring to the
ancient Semitic language, now mostly extinct, that originated among a
people known as the Aramaeans around the late 11th century B.C. As
reported in the Washington Post, a version of it is still spoken today
by communities of Chaldean Christians in Iraq and Syria.
“He spoke Aramaic, but he knew Hebrew,” Netanyahu replied quickly.

News of the linguistic disagreement made headlines, but it turns out both the prime minister and the Pope were likely right.
What Language did Jesus Speak? Aramaic, Hebrew or Greek? (christianity.com)
The Language of Jesus: Aramaic

It is the general consensus of religious scholars and historians that
Jesus and his disciples primarily spoke Aramaic, the traditional
language of Judea in the first century AD. Their Aramaic was most
likely a Galilean accent distinct from that of Jerusalem. Jesus spent
most of his time in the communities of Nazareth and Capernaum in
Galilee, which were Aramaic-speaking villages. The Gospels support
this view showing Jesus using various Aramaic terms: talitha koum
(Mark 5:41); ephphatha (Mark 7:34); eloi eloi lama sabachthani
(Matthew 27:46; Mark 15:34); abba (Mark 14:36). Historians,
scientists, and social anthropologists largely agree that Aramaic was
the prevalent language in Israel during Jesus’ time. Aramaic was very
similar to Hebrew, but with many terms and expressions that were
acquired from other languages and cultures, notably Babylonian.


Any answer is, at best, an informed guess. There is no way to reach a decisive conclusion.

I agree with the multiple comments that we really do not know the answer to this question. The comments are enlightening but speculation.

We are talking of Jesus who knew what men were thinking. Such a man, could speak any language, if he so chooses. Since there are no documents as to what Jesus choose to speak, the question is hard to get decisive answer. I agree with @DavidD

When Jesus read from the Scrolls in the synagogue, as reported by the gospel writers, we have several possibilities:

Jesus read aloud in Hebrew and then preached in Hebrew, but the gospel writer recorded all events in Greek.
Jesus read aloud in Hebrew, then translated to Aramaic, but the gospel writer recorded all events in Greek.
Jesus read aloud from the Septuagint (ie, Greek) but preached in Aramaic, but the gospel writer recorded all events in Greek.
Jesus read aloud from the Septuagint (ie, Greek), then translated to Aramaic, but preached in Aramaic
etc

Now what are the facts we know about this?  We have no facts and so we cannot know which of these occurred.  All are possible.  Further, it is also possible that Jesus varied His practice depending on the audience and situation.
Thus, we do not have enough information to answer the OP's question.

you say reported by 'gospel writers' - from my understanding only Luke mentions about the reading of Isaiah - hence my Q - how would Luke know and why would it not be reported by the others who witnessed it when talking about the same event - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/90894/33268

@anothertheory - exactly the same question could be asked of the dozens of other incidents - some reported by one or more evangelists and omitted by others.  Each writer selected, under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit, which incidents to include and exclude according to the divine purpose.  Put this question on your list to ask Luke when you meet him.

@anothertheory presumably the other gospel writers thought it not important to mention, because it's either obvious to their audience which scripture Jesus was referring to, or because they were simply focussing on different things.

@Dottard Yes one of the usual excuse - but the point I was making is that it was ‘writer’ not with a 's' at the end.  Inspired Luke 1:1-3 - 1 Many have undertaken to draw up an account of the things that have been fulfilled among us, 2 just as they were handed down to us by those who from the first were eyewitnesses and servants of the word. 3 With this in mind, since I myself have carefully investigated everything from the beginning, I too decided to write an orderly account.....'

Written Languages
In Jesus' day, the Jewish scriptures existed almost exclusively in 2 languages:

The Hebrew Tanakh, Hebrew being the original language of nearly all Jewish sacred writings
The Greek Septuagint, a translation of the Hebrew scriptures into Greek carried out 2-3 centuries before Christ

What about Aramaic?
--
Targums
Targums
As Claude Tresmontant observed,

There were oral translations in Aramaic of the sacred books written in Hebrew; they were called targumin. A translator in the synagogue would read aloud, translating a passage from the Torah or one of the prophets. But in the era before the destruction of the Temple, putting these translations into writing was formally prohibited." (The Hebrew Christ p. 5)

So the sacred writings in the local synagogues would be documents written in Hebrew (unless in a Greek dominated region), from which Aramaic oral translations were sometimes given.
--
Spoken Languages
In all likelihood, Jesus spoke 3 languages:

Aramaic: the language of the home. Some of Jesus' statements in Aramaic are preserved in the New Testament, as ably demonstrated by Dieter.
Hebrew: the language of the synagogue. A rabbi teaching from the scriptures (which Jesus did regularly) would have to be able to communicate in Hebrew. Evidences of Hebrew's existence as a living language in the first-century are reviewed in my post here. Baltes reviews here the history & motivations behind some scholars' efforts to convince the world that Jesus didn't speak Hebrew.
Greek: the language of the marketplace. Interaction with Gentiles from the surrounding cities of the Decapolis, commerce & trade, and communication with Roman rulers would all have been dominated by Greek.

(Latin would not have been spoken by Galilean or Judean Jews. In the eastern Roman Empire Greek was the lingua franca; Latin would have only been used by Romans among themselves, such as for governmental or military communications)
--
The specific case in Nazareth
We are not told whether the scroll in Luke 4 was written in Hebrew or Greek, but odds are very good that it was Hebrew. Nazareth was not a major commercial center (e.g. see John 1:46), a juncture on a trade route like Capernaum, or a site of pilgrimage like Jerusalem.
A small town like Nazareth would be extraordinarily unlikely to have Greek scriptures, which would have been found in explicitly Greek synagogues (common among Jews of the diaspora, possible in Jerusalem, very unlikely in Galilee).
--
Conclusion
In Luke 4, Jesus probably read from a Hebrew scroll. After reading, it would not have been unusual to give a translation or a commentary in Aramaic.

“A small town like Nazareth would be extraordinarily unlikely to have Greek scriptures” - why is the quotation in Luke from the LXX then?

@AviAvraham great question , but probably beyond the scope of the original question. I offered an answer to a related question here.

it may be worth specifically calling out Targum Onkelos, which is essentially the canonical Jewish Aramaic translation of the Hebrew Bible which (likely) dates to the 2nd century CE, adding further weight to the idea that it would be unlikely for him to read from an Aramaic translation

@Tristan Targum Onkelos is only on the Pentateuch. There is an older Aramaic translation on the prophets.

good point on it being Torah only. From what I've seen though, Targum Yonatan is also generally thought to be from the 2nd century CE (although the traditional attribution to Jonathan ben Uzziel would require it to be earlier)

Several languages were spoken in Judea during the time of Jesus and they had interesting origins!
Aramaic. The numerous Aramaean people of ancient Syria migrated southeastward spreading their language throughout Mesopotamia, including Babylon, where many Judeans were later forcibly exiled and resettled by the Babylonian King Nebuchadnezzar II in 582 BC. When the Judeans returned starting to Israel in 538 BC, the language they brought back with them was Aramaic. This was the prevailing language of the common people in Galilee, Samaria, and Judea during the time of Jesus. The book of Matthew might have been originally written in Aramaic and some of the words of Jesus have been left untranslated in the gospel accounts: talitha koum (Mark 5:41); ephphatha (Mark 7:34); eloi eloi lama sabachthani (Matthew 27:46; Mark 15:34); abba (Mark 14:36).
Hebrew. Hebrew was used primarily by the religious elite, including scribes, teachers of the law, Pharisees, and Sadducees. Hebrew was likely spoken and read in the synagogues, so most of the common people understood some Hebrew. Hebrew and Aramaic are closely related, however there are several measures of nearness used by linguists.
A crude measure considers only the consonants used in common words. By that measure, Hebrew vs (Syriac) Aramaic has a score of 25.7 on a scale of 0 (identical) to 100 (78 is considered unintelligible). On that scale, French vs Portuguese scores a 27.1 and English vs German scores a 31.3. Again, there are many other measures.
Here's a famous example, Psalm 22:1a. In this case, it demonstrates considerable similarity between Hebrew and Aramaic:
English: My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?
Hebrew: ’êlî ’êlî lāmāh ‘ăzaḇtānî
Aramaic: eloi eloi lama sabachthani (from Matthew 27:46)
Here are some Aramaic/Hebrew word-pair pronunciations: ruach/ruah, Yahuah/Yahweh (or Yahuweh), Alahim/Elohim.
Greek. Alexander the Great, conquered all of the areas covered by modern-day Greece, part of Bulgaria, Turkey, Syria, Israel, Egypt, Iran, Iraq, Afghanistan, and Pakistan. He brought Greek philosophy and culture into all these areas. When Alexander the Great died in 323 BC, his empire was divided between his four generals. But by 160 BC, Jewish fighters under Judah Maccabee gained freedom for Judea. However, the Romans conquered Judea and surrounding areas by 63 BC and installed Herod the Great as King of the Jews in 40 BC.
Thus, in these areas at the time of Jesus, Greek was the primary language of commerce, the wealthy, and the political rulers. Greek was commonly spoken by Judean expatriates, and Latin was used by the Romans only for legal and military matters.
I believe there's biblical evidence that Jesus spoke all three of these languages, but that's another topic.

This doesn't really answer the question about the reading of Isaiah in the synagogue

Relying on numerous sources, I wrote "Hebrew was likely spoken and read in the synagogues."  This answers the question of what language Jesus read from. There's no indication whether he simultaneously translated the Hebrew into Aramaic as he read the scroll or whether the scroll that he read from was an Aramaic translation of Hebrew. We have no way of knowing this information and the most likely answer is that he read the scroll in Hebrew. The DSS include 21 manuscripts of Isaiah written in Hebrew, the most complete one being IQIsa.

This really is useful information, but it needs to address what language Jesus spoke when reading the scroll in the Synagogue.

We can consider only likelihoods in the absence of any definitive assertions in the scriptures. It says that Jesus read from the scroll, but it doesn't say that he translated from the scroll or paraphrased it. His Galilean audience spoke Aramaic, probably understood some Hebrew, but not much Greek. The scroll itself was written in Hebrew. So, after Jesus read from the scroll, in Hebrew, his comments to his listeners would have been in Aramaic.

I've added one famous example to compare biblical Hebrew and first century Aramaic to my answer above.

This question is posed as a historical question, so it deserves an accurate historical answer that treats Luke as a historical source. That's inevitably going to conflict with religious fundamentalist and biblical literalist readings of the text.
The prologue of Luke makes it impossible to interpret it as an eyewitness account. The textual history of Luke shows a lot of variation extending into the second century. Luke's depiction often conflicts with the Pauline epistles, which are clearly historical documents from the first century. The author of Luke is mainly concerned with gentile issues, and wants gentiles not to have to become Jews in order to become Christians. So the general picture of whoever wrote Luke is that this person is very far removed from the events of Jesus's life -- far removed in space, time, and culture.
For these reasons, it doesn't really make sense to assume that this story is literally true and then try to shoehorn it into a possible historical context. In the second century, Christians were seen as disreputable by the dominant culture for a variety of reasons, one of which was that they often recruited their members from the poor, women, and uneducated people. To counteract this, it would be desirable to depict Jesus as a highly educated person. This passage from Luke also shows Jesus presenting himself as fulfilling the prophecies of the Jewish scriptures, which was a characteristic thing to do among second-century Christians. The author of Luke was probably a Greek-speaking gentile, had probably only seen the Jewish scriptures through the Septuagint, and may have had no clear idea that Aramaic was distinct from Hebrew, or that people in first-century Galilee couldn't understand Hebrew. This passage certainly doesn't show any awareness of such a fact.
Because Jesus was the son of a carpenter from Galilee, it's extremely likely that Aramaic was the only language he spoke, and also that he was illiterate. He would probably have known the Jewish scriptures only from hearing the targums orally. It is especially unlikely that he had the high level of scribal literacy that would have been required in order to read such a scroll fluently on sight. These scrolls were not easy documents to read. They had no word breaks or vowels, and no tables of contents or easy methods of locating the desired spot in the text. Jesus's scorn for "scribes and pharisees" is consistent with the fact that his literacy, if any, was not at a scribal level.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


What language did Jesus speak when he read Isaiah 61:1,2?

Either the Galilean dialect of Aramaic, or the ancient Hebrew, depending on the written language of the scroll.  Both are plausible.  I think the scroll is more likely to have been written in ancient Hebrew, the original language of Isaiah, but I think Jesus may have either read it in Aramaic directly or read it in both Hebrew and Aramaic.

Would Aramaic be spoken in the synagogue?

In a Galilean synagogue, certainly.  But the Isaiah scroll still could have been read in the ancient Hebrew instead, and then again in Aramaic, as it is today read in Hebrew even in synagogues where most people do not speak Hebrew.
There is enough evidence to be gathered from the New Testament, ancient historians, and modern archaeology and research to confidently conclude:

The primary vernacular language of Judea, Samaria and the Galilee in Jesus' day was the Hebrew dialect of Aramaic (in academic literature often called 'Palestinian' Aramaic).
Jesus himself, his disciples, and most Jews and even Samaritans living in those areas primarily spoke Aramaic.
Jesus may have been capable of reading and speaking the ancient Hebrew and understanding it:

He read from the Isaiah scroll in synagogue, which was originally composed in the ancient Hebrew.
Luke informs us of a time in Jesus' youth when he spent days at the Temple engaging with the teachers there, who were impressed with him.
It is plausible that Jesus had spent time during his regular trips to Jerusalem and on Sabbath days with the local rabbi learning the scriptures and how to read and speak the old Hebrew.


But the possibility cannot be ignored that when he read the Isaiah scroll, he was reading from a translation into Aramaic, the language everyone there actually spoke.

Evidence to support these conclusions includes:

From the New Testament passage, Jesus first reads the portion from the prophet Isaiah, stops, and then announces, "Today this saying is fulfilled in your hearing."  And then he sits down, and a huge drama unfolds.  This implies that what he has just read, everyone there understood.  We can infer that he was not reading only in the ancient Hebrew.  (Nor in Greek, as we will see.)  He was either reading in both Hebrew and Aramaic, or only in Aramaic.

Numerous quotations, phrases and individual words in the Greek New Testament that remain in the Aramaic language but are transliterated into Greek prove that Aramaic was the vernacular language - a few examples:

Eloi eloi lama sabachthani? spoken from the cross ("My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?") - although in the Aramaic New Testament lemana not lama is quoted, having a much different meaning.
Even some apparently mundane quotations are given in Aramaic in the Greek New Testament that have no obvious spiritual depth, such as Talitha cumi ("Young maid arise").
Other single-word transliterations of Aramaic words are:

Messiah in John 4:25
Keefa ("Cephas", Romanized as "Peter") meaning 'stone' as a nickname for Simon (the other disciples were teasing him for being dumb as a stone)
Beelzebub means "the master of flies" or "the lord of the flies".
Many occurrences of "Satan" which is the word for 'Enemy' in both Aramaic and ancient Hebrew.  At times we find "enemy" in the Greek New Testament where "Satan" as a name would also make sense (Luke 10:19); and at times we find "Satan" as a name where it doesn't make as much sense as "enemy", like "the synagogue of Satan" or the famous quote, "Get thee behind me Satan", which makes much less sense in context than "Get thee behind me enemy" does.


Many place names and personal names from the New Testament are meaningful in Aramaic but not in Greek.

The "Aenon springs" where John the Baptist worked.  In Aramaic Ain-yon means "spring of doves".  It is quite plausible that doves would congregate near a natural spring in a low-lying plain with many tall reeds growing all around.
"Bethsaida" is Beit Chisda meaning "house of the faithful".


Even in the Pauline epistles we can find Aramaic vernacular in plain sight, such as in the transliterated Maranatha which can either be Maran atha ("the Master has come") or Marana tha ("Master, come").  Many ancient manuscripts lacked space between words.  Could it be that the scribe who translated 1 Corinthians into Greek (!) couldn't decide which meaning was intended?


There are some cases where it seems the Aramaic original New Testament dialogue was awkwardly translated to Greek due to ambiguities in written Aramaic text.  Two cases:

The word גמלא is found in Aramaic Matthew 19:24 and can be read as gamala 'heavy rope' or gumala 'camel' as the vowel sounds must be inferred.  So is it harder for a camel to go through the eye of a needle, or for a rope to go through the eye of a needle?
Similarly, גרבא in Aramaic Matthew 26:6 and Mark 14:3 can be read as garba 'leper' or garaba 'potter'.  A house party with VIP guests hosted by a leper is completely incredible, but one hosted by a potter is perfectly plausible.


There are numerous uses of Aramaic language idioms in the four gospels.  Some have become idioms in modern English due to the Bible's influence on culture, but many would have been quite strange to a native Greek speaker of that time.  George Lamsa's books explain many Biblical idioms and cultural references.

"If your eye offends you pluck it out."  If you are inclined to envy, avoid what tempts you.
"If your hand offends you cut it off."  If you are inclined to steal, avoid what tempts you.
"I and my father are one."  We agree fully; there is 'no daylight between us'.  (The Pharisees, being Judean, misunderstood this Galilean idiom and took the statement literally, and accused him falsely of making himself equal with God.  Had Jesus really meant that literally, they would have been right to accuse him!  Remember, Paul wrote that Jesus "did not consider equality with God a thing to be attained".)
"Sell your cloak and buy a sword."  Beware, danger is near.
"Let me first bury my father."  My father will die soon.
"A man was in Abraham's bosom."  The man was buried with his ancestors.
"If a man does not hate his father and his mother..."  This is hyperbole.  The parents' concerns are to be considered relatively lower in importance.
Many others.


In Luke's Gospel, when Zechariah speaks after the naming of John (Yochannan, "God is gracious"), his words in Aramaic constitute a poem in the standard form of that period, with three stanzas (past, present, future) of seven verses each (not lining up with the modern verse numbering), and having meter and alliteration.  In Greek it is just prose.  Surely Zechariah's original words were in Aramaic.

The sect of the Pharisees, which later became Rabbinic Judaism, and which the teachings of both John the Baptist and Jesus himself align with more closely than other divisions of Judaism of that time, also used their dialect of Aramaic as a vernacular language while preserving the old Hebrew scriptures and other ancient texts.  Perhaps the best proof of this is the existence of the Jerusalem Talmud which is written in Aramaic, not Hebrew.  (By the time of the Babylonian Talmud, composed later, the Jewish diaspora had returned to the old Hebrew for religious matters.)

Aramaic as the language of mainstream Judaism is bookended by its use in Daniel and Jeremiah from the period of the Captivity, until the time of the Masoretes between the writing of the Jerusalem and the Babylonian Talmud.

Further proof of Hebrew-Aramaic as the Second Temple vernacular language are the many Aramaic targums that were written in those years, and the fact that early Christian communities to come out of Jerusalem were Aramaic-speaking.  There are Aramaic speaking Christian churches today that draw continuity from those early Christians.  They are living proof of the first century AD Aramaic-speaking church.

The Jewish historian Josephus wrote in his Antiquities of the Jews, volume 20 chapter 11, that "our nation" frowns upon people who learn other languages such as Greek, considering it a "common" (vulgar) accomplishment.  Josephus himself learned Greek because he was an officer in the Roman military, eventually even having a friendly relationship with the Emperor.  His claim is debated because there definitely were 'Hellenist' Jews who embraced Greek language, philosophy, culture and even religion; but it seems that the Pharisees, later the Rabbis, considered them as outsiders.

The 'church fathers' of the first four centuries AD attested multiple times to the fact that the Gospel of Matthew was originally composed in Hebrew script (which was the preferred script in Judea for writing Aramaic).  Jerome (342-420), the translator of the Vulgate, wrote in On Famous Men 3;5:

Matthew ... composed a Gospel of Messiah in Judea in the Hebrew language and letters, for the benefit of those of the circumcision who had believed, who translated it into Greek is not sufficiently ascertained. Furthermore, the Hebrew itself is preserved to this day in the library at Caesarea, which the martyr Pamphilus so diligently collected. I also was allowed by the Nazarenes who use this volume in the Syrian city of Borea to copy it. In which it is to be remarked that, wherever the evangelist ... makes use of the testimonies
of the Old Scripture, he does not follow the authority of the seventy translators but that of the Hebrew.


Other sources agreeing that Matthew was originally written in Hebrew script are:

Eusebius (Ecclesiastical History, 3.24, 3:38.2-3, 3:39, 5.10, and 6.25)
Epiphanus (Panarion 29.9.4)
Irenaeus (Against Heresies 3.1)
Clement of Alexandria, preserved in quotation by Eusebius EH 6.14.2


Returning to the New Testament text, after Jesus' arrest, Simon Peter was accused of being his disciple based on his Galilean accent!  ("You speak like a Galilean" he was told.)  So if the vernacular language of the Galilee was Aramaic, and it was (Talitha cumi was spoken to a girl living by the Sea of Galilee), then the language of Jerusalem must have been as well.

The placard hung on the cross had the phrase, "Jesus of Nazareth King of the Jews", written in three languages: Latin (the official language of Rome), Greek (the lingua franca of the Roman Empire) and "Hebrew" (Aramaic using Hebrew script).  This shows that anyone who was literate and might see the placard near the gate into Jerusalem could probably read one of those three.


As to the 'Old Testament' quotations found in the Greek New Testament books: In most cases the phrasing used in the quotations agrees closely with the Septuagint (LXX), a third century BC translation into Greek.  People, even scholars, have inferred all kinds of things from this.  But to me the common sense conclusion is obvious.  The Greek-literate scribe had the LXX available to him, and simply copied from it rather than go through the unnecessary and risky effort to translate holy writ into Greek again himself.
So the fact that we read LXX Greek text in the Greek New Testament narrative of Jesus reading the Isaiah scroll does not really tell us anything about the language that scroll was written in.  Because the Greek scribe's objective was to give us the Greek quotation from Isaiah, not to transliterate the exact words spoken, and the existing LXX translation of Isaiah served the purpose just fine.
It is interesting that Jerome, above, tells us that in Matthew's original "Hebrew" (we can infer, Aramaic in Hebrew script) gospel text, the quotations are also in Hebrew script, not Greek.  This fact alone also does not tell us anything about the language that the scroll Jesus read from was written in.  It does tell us that Matthew was writing for either a Hebrew-literate or an Aramaic-literate audience, and it makes it likely that Matthew had a Hebrew-script Isaiah at hand to quote from.
Jerome's phrasing, "the authority ... of the Hebrew" may additionally tell us that Matthew's original quotations, as Jerome read them, were in the Hebrew language (the language of the book of Isaiah) as well as Hebrew script.  Jerome says "Hebrew language and letters", but what he calls 'Hebrew' may be what academics today call 'Palestinian Aramaic'.  Or he may in fact mean the ancient Hebrew.

In Luke 24:27

And beginning with Moses and all the Prophets, he explained to them what was said in all the Scriptures concerning himself.

The Greek verb translated as "he explained" is διερμηνεύω (diermēneuō). This verb is significant and reveals much about Jesus's ability to interpret the Scriptures. Here's a detailed breakdown:
1. Meaning of διερμηνεύω

The verb διερμηνεύω means "to interpret," "to explain," or "to make clear." It combines δι- ("thoroughly" or "completely") with ἑρμηνεύω (hermēneuō), which is related to Hermes, the Greek god of communication and interpretation.
In biblical usage, it often refers to making complex or hidden ideas understandable.

2. Connection to Translation

While διερμηνεύω does not exclusively refer to linguistic translation, it can encompass the idea of translating concepts. It involves rendering something comprehensible to the listener or reader.
In this context, Jesus was not merely explaining but also "translating" the deeper meanings of the Scriptures in a way that illuminated their prophetic fulfillment in himself.

3. Jesus's Role as an Interpreter

Jesus demonstrated profound insight into the Scriptures, going beyond their surface meaning. He was able to "translate" their symbols, prophecies, and promises to show how they pointed to him.
This ability highlights his divine role as the ultimate teacher, unveiling truths that were previously misunderstood or hidden.

4. Context in Luke 24:27
On the road to Emmaus, Jesus used διερμηνεύω to clarify passages that the disciples struggled to understand. He effectively "translated" the prophetic and spiritual meaning of the Law of Moses and the Prophets, showing how they converged on his life, death, and resurrection.
In summary, the use of διερμηνεύω emphasizes Jesus's unique ability to translate, interpret, and clarify the Scriptures, helping his disciples grasp their fulfillment in him.

Jn 19:19-20 comes handy as a useful reference on how the lay Jews were able to read and understand Hebrew and Greek .

And Pilate wrote a title, and put it on the cross. And the writing was Jesus Of Nazareth The King Of The Jews.This title then read many of the Jews: for the place where Jesus was crucified was nigh to the city: and it was written in Hebrew, and Greek, and Latin.

The scroll from which Jesus read  may have been either in Hebrew or in Greek. His audience understood the message,  even if he did not translate it into Aramaic.  In fact, Lk 4:20-21 implies that Jesus allowed the text to sink deep into the heart of his listeners, without the need for Aramaic translation :

And he closed the book, and he gave it again to the minister, and sat down. And the eyes of all them that were in the synagogue were fastened on him.And he began to say unto them, This day is this scripture fulfilled in your ears.

But there is catch in Verse 22:

And all bare him witness, and wondered at the gracious words which proceeded out of his mouth. And they said, Is not this Joseph's son?

Read that again with  Verse 21 that says:".. and he began to say..." In fact, Jesus' reference to the fulfilment of Isiah' s prophecy was only an introduction .He explained at length how the prophecy was being fulfilled. Had he only read out from the scroll with an  Aramaic translation, there was no scope for the people wondering ' at the gracious words  that fell from his mouth'. Thus, Jesus went beyond mere translation. He presented  the scripture in the  most lively and comprehensible manner !
