Is there an Order of Precedence in the three attributes of Christ the Saviour as mentioned in Jn 14:6?
We hear Jesus declaring that he is The Way, The Truth and The Life ( Jn 14:6).
Assuming that the three attributes are presented in the sequence they apply to a believer, he/she would have to first follow Jesus, secondly  embrace The Truth and thereby be rewarded with Eternal Life.
Now, permit me to quote from an Answer to my earlier question on the topic:

Every word of Jesus, recorded in all the gospel accounts, relates to the gospel truth we need to believe as Truth, in order to start following the Way, and to gain the Life.

That sequence of action viz. , first to believe in The Truth, then to follow Jesus who is The Way and to gain Eternal Life, also sounds logical. Thus we would say : Jesus is The Truth, The Way and the Life.   That sequence however, deviates from the one in Jn 14:6 .  My question therefore is: Is there an Order of Precedence in the three attributes of Christ the Saviour  as mentioned in Jn 14:6 ?

I do not understand the question. Jesus states the three items, one after the other, in order. The Order of Precedence (to which you refer) is the order in which he spoke them. The 'way' is not (as you seem to state) the way to Jesus, but, in context of 14:6b - the way to the Father.  The verse is about finding God, the Father, through Jesus Christ.

Thanks, Nigel J.  Would Jesus miss something out if he only said : " I am the Way and the Life " ?

If the New Testament consistently described Jesus as "the Way, the Truth, and the Life", in that precise order, then the answer would likely be "Yes, there seems to be an order of precedence." And that answer would need to be backed up with all the other places in the scriptures that give that order.
However, right at the start of John's gospel account about Jesus, the order is quite different. We know from 1:16 that it is Jesus Christ who is the One being introduced to us in that opening chapter.
First, he is introduced to us as the Word of God, who became flesh as the man, Jesus Christ, at a certain point in time (vss. 1 & 14). Second, he is introduced to us as "the life" in verse 4. Then we are told he is the truth in verses 14 and 17. Next, we are told from verse 27 to the end of chapter 1 that after John the Baptist testified about Jesus, disciples started to follow Jesus - believing him to be the Christ. That could be said to be the beginning of people seeing Jesus as "the way".
I will now quote those verses, in order, to let you see the progression as the Apostle John puts it, prior to Jesus calling himself the Way, the Truth, and the Life in chapter 14:

"In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the
Word was God" (v.1)
"And the Word was made flesh and dwelt among us" (v.14.a)
"In him was life; and the life was the light of men" (v.4)
"...and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the one only begotten of
the Father, full of grace and truth" (v.14.b)
"...grace and truth came by Jesus Christ" (v.17)

So, John initially has us consider Christ as the Life, and the Truth, and then once people believe that, they start following him as the Way. Bear in mind that John also spoke in chapter 1 of Jesus being the light of the world, "that all through him might believe" (v.7) "..the true Light, which lighteth every man that cometh into the world" (v.9).
This is significant, as nobody can "see" the way to go if in the darkness. Light is needed to see the way. Jesus is that true Light. John's order, then, is that Jesus is the Life, the Light, and the Truth.
Spiritual light is needed to see Jesus for who he truly is, to grasp that he is the Truth, and that if we are to have life eternal, we must follow him as the only Way to the father - "...the only begotten Son, who in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him." John 1:18
Those are my initial thoughts, and I do not have time right now to explore further, but I will be interested to read other answers. My answer is simply, "No, the order in John 14:6 does not set a precedent that must always be followed."

+1.  Good Answer!

You could also be showing that there is an order and John 1 presents a Chiasmus! John 1 is how Jesus presents himself to us - Life, Truth, Way, and then John 14 shows the order in which we respond, Way, Truth, Life. There are places in Scripture where things are sequenced two ways, one showing God approaching us and the other showing us approaching God. This might be another...

Besides Jesus' declaration in John 14:6 that He is the Way, the Truth, and the Life, Jesus also declares that He is:

The Bread of Life (John 6:35)
The Light of the World (John 8:12)
The Gate for the Sheep (John 10:9)
The Good Shepherd (John 10:11)
The True Vine (John 15:1)

Knowing Jesus is the way does not necessarily mean knowing the way, and similarly, knowing Jesus is the Truth does not automatically mean understanding the Truth. Therefore, something even more fundamental is highlighted in Ephesians 2:8-9:

8 For it is by grace you have been saved, through faith—and this is not from yourselves, it is the gift of God— 9 not by works, so that no one can boast.

Christianity emphasizes faith in Jesus Christ. However, it can be challenging to realize that, according to Paul, faith itself is a gift from God, not something one can achieve through their own works. In Matthew 19:25, the disciples asked Jesus,“Who then can be saved?” Jesus replies in Matthew 19:26, “With man this is impossible, but with God all things are possible.”
Therefore, Jesus is not limited to the three attributes mentioned in John 14:6. These attributes do not establish an order of precedence for acquiring eternal life. Instead, we might wonder, by what criteria does God offer His gift to someone?
This principle may reflect in both James 4:6 and 1 Peter 5:5: “God opposes the proud but shows favor to the humble.” This statement refers to Proverbs 3:34, which states:

He (God) mocks proud mockers
but shows favor to the humble and oppressed. (NIV)

Jesus also teaches in Matthew 18:4:

Whosoever therefore shall humble himself as this little child, the same is greatest in the kingdom of heaven. (KJV)

The word "humble" resonates with Paul's statement in Ephesians 2:8-9, emphasizing that "no one can boast".

There is no particular relevance to the order of the saying in Jn 14:6.
Some use John 14:6 6 Jesus answered, “I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me - as evidence of trinity.


The saying doesn’t prove in any way that Jesus is God or part of the godhead.




Jesus clearly says he is the way (the manner in which you can achieve something) not the destination  [ meaning God] Here Jesus clearly means that he is messenger[ way] to destinations  [ God]




Others have also been the way, prophets Abraham replied, Luke 16:27-31 ‘They have Moses and the Prophets; let them listen to them.’  Noah, but his people refused to follow him, Jonah for the people of Nineveh, John the Baptist Matt 21:32 For John came unto you in the way of righteousness, and ye believed him not:




If Jesus was the ‘only’ way, then all before did not have a chance, including Noah, Abraham etc…




The simple answer is that to achieve success you need to follow the message of God, at that time Jesus was the way to the truth (sent to the lost sheep of Israel) as was others before him. Jesus recognised God, prayed / worshipped  to the ONE true God;



John 17:3 “…that they might know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom you have sent.”

Luke 6:12 “he continued all night in prayer to God.”
Matthew 26:39 ‘…he fell with his face to the ground and prayed, ‘My Father…”
Hebrews 5:7 “During the days of Jesus' life on earth, he offered up prayers and petitions with loud cries and tears to the one who could save him from death, and he was heard because of his reverent submission.” [ only one saviour – not Jesus]
Luke 1:47  And my spirit hath rejoiced in God my Saviour


Differentiation between Jesus and God –
Jn 14
1 "Do not let your hearts be troubled. Trust in God; trust also in me.
2 In my Father's house are many rooms; if it were not so, I would have told
you. I am going there to prepare a place for you.




8Philip said, "Lord, show us the Father and that will be enough for us." – again this is not physically seeing the father, but guiding us to God.  They were well aware they cannot see God;


“No one has ever seen God” (John 1:18),
And the Father Himself, who sent Me, has testified of Me. You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form. (John 5:37)
“But," he God said, "you cannot see my face, for no one may see me and live." (Exodus 33:20)]


Even after resurrection - 1John 4:12 - No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God lives in us and his love is made complete in us. [ by knowing Jesus one gets to know about God]




John 17:3 And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.




Last but not least we have to be careful accepting what may have been written in John.  Must consider that he was the last Gospel, not only do we not know who wrote it, no one else mentions many of these so called saying of Jesus that John mentions, such as;


John 14:9: "Whoever has seen me has seen the Father."
John 6:35: "And Jesus said unto them, I am the bread of life."
John 8:12: "I am the light of the world."
John 8:58: "Before Abraham was, I am."
John 10:7: "I am the door of the sheep."
John 11 :25: "I am the resurrection, and the life."
John 14:6: "I am the way, the truth, and the life."
John 15: 1 "I am the true vine."
Most scholars are sceptic of certain teachings as being later additions, to quote one;  ‘The New American Bible’ says that most scholars "have come to the conclusion that the inconsistencies were probably produced by subsequent editing in which homogeneous materials were added to a shorter original."(New American Bible, Revised New Testament. p. 143)
The American Bishop John Shelby Spong said: intensive five-year-long study of John’s Gospel - There is probably not a single word attributed to Jesus in this book that the Jesus of history actually spoke
The issues in John is a very extensive study, this is just a brief gloss.
Reliability of the Gospel of John: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/63568/33268

@ another theory, so are you suggesting that the Gospel according to John was not ' inspired' ? Is it not possible that he incorporated a little bit of literature and imagery to make his work interesting ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Many things are possible.  Symbol of Christianity / Jesus was initially a Fish.   The cross was used prior to Christianity in Hinduism &  pagan worship, the most noticeable CRUX ANSATA (pagan Egyptians).
Divine trinity - "Tri-murti" (Three-forms) consisting of Brahma, Vishnu, and Siva – inseparable unity through three in one deity [long before Christianity]

Celebrations 25 December - birthday of Hercules, the son of the supreme god of the Greeks / The pagan god Buddha is believed to have been born on this day when the "Holy Ghost" descended on his virgin mother Maya / supreme god of the heavens, Odin / Romans observed this day as the birth day of the god of the sun, Natalis Solis Invicti – so on……

as an Indian, I never heard that Hindus used the cross. What they have is the Svastik, which is an inverted form of Nazi emblem. Its hands are of equal length and bend at the end. The Cross of Christianity came from the cross on which Jesus was crucified. It in fact had been a symbol of shame ! It has distinct origin as shape vis a vis the Swastik of Hinduism. (.NB: When a non- Christian abuses a Kerala Christian, he uses a word that translates as ' son of the one who went to the gallows!)

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Teh abvoe were just a few of many examples available and conveneintly you have ignored but one point.  Swastika is a cross with arms but was initially just two lines crossing each other.  The cross is probably the most ancient symbol and had various looks, not as we understand it today.  Logos theory is Aryan and likely Hindu origin.  They have Gods first begotten son being sacrificed being fastened to posts & crosses.  There is so much about pagan influence on the internet
